# (React)I want to pass the url value of the image with another component and erase it, but it doesn't

Tags: reactjs

I wrote about this problem, but it hasn't been solved, so I'll write it again. Please understand. I'm making a function that allows me to register an image in one component to see the image in another component and delete the image. If I register an image in child component, I can see the image well in parent component, but I can't delete the image. When I delete the image, it was deleted immediately and the original url came back in. I think there is a problem in this part when the value is handed over from child component to parent component in the form of a function. When I did it with one component, the image was erased well. But I'm working on two components separately. Delete the image should be done by making the url of the image "". How can I solve this problem? I'd appreciate it if you let me know, thanks.

**Cild.jsx:**

this is child component. Upload the image here and pass the url value to parent component through 'toParent'

```js
   import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

   function Child({toParent}) {


//file upload functions
const fileInput = React.useRef(null);

const [isfile,setIsfile] = useState("");

const handleButtonClick = e => {
  fileInput.current.click();
};

const handleChange = e => {
  setIsfile(e.target.files[0]);
  console.log(e.target.files[0]);
}; 

const [preview, setPreview] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
if (isfile) {
  const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(isfile); 
    setPreview(objectUrl);
  }
  return () => URL.revokeObjectURL(isfile);      
}, [isfile]);

//pass state to parent
toParent(preview)

return (
 <h1>
  <input 
    type="file" 
    style={{display:'none'}}
    ref={fileInput}
    onChange={handleChange}
    multiple={true}/>
  <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>
    upload
  </button>
  </h1>
)
}

export default Child;
```

**App.js:**

and this is parent component. Get the url value here and show the image. Also, if I press delete, I want to empty the url of the image, but I can't. How can I empth the url??

```js
   import { useState } from "react";
   import Child from "./Child";

function App() {

//receive state from child
const [isUrl,setIsUrl] = useState("")
const toParent = (url) => {
  setIsUrl(url);
}

//delete image
const handelDelete = (e) => {
  setIsUrl(" ")
}

return (
<div className="App">
  <Child toParent={toParent} />
  <div>
    <img 
    style={{width:'300px', height:'300px'}}
    src={isUrl}/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div onClick={handelDelete}>
      delete
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
   }

  export default App;
```

Comment: On deleting image in parent component you need to pass that state to the child and make sure it is in sync with the similar state in child. Else the child state preview will always have a value and since the toParent callback isn't wrapped in useEffect hook it'll run everytime setting a value to isUrl state. You could move all the code in useEffect and toParent callback inside handleChange method.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand the meaning, but can I know how to change the code?